# Firestore image url to base64 conversion

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need code for Firestore url to base64 conversion and bind it to src to generate pdf
I tried with

Method 1:

```
getBase64ImageFromUrl(imageUrl) {
         var img = new Image();
         img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
         img.src = imageUrl;
         const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
         const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
         context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
         const url = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
         return url;
       }
```

Method 2:

```
toDataURL(url, callback) {
         var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhr.onload = function() {
           var reader = new FileReader();
           reader.onloadend = function() {
             callback(reader.result);
           }
           reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
         };
         xhr.open('GET', url);
         xhr.responseType = 'blob';
         xhr.send();
       }
```

Method 3:

Used functions and got the converted base64 data but when I tried to bind with the image src I am not able to get the image in pdf.
Is there any other way to get the conversion without using functions.
I am working with typescript code from Firestore. 
When I tried with the local image link I get the solution but when I use Firestore image url I am not able to bind it with src

Comment: could you share the code of the third option you used and the second part of your process please?

Comment: Com sua primeira alternativa resolveu meu problema de compartilhamento no facebook. Obrigado